# How do I simulate web page button click in c#

Tags: c#, browser, web

I know it can be done by
`webBrower.Document.GetElementById("Id_Of_Element").InvokeMembers("Click")` method by I have trouble finding it's ID. is there any other way I can do that. Web Page URL is this
http://www.magtifun.ge/index.php?page=1&lang=en
I need to simulate press on "Sign In" Button !

Comment: You're having trouble finding the id because it doesn't have one. You could use alternative methods such as `getElementsByTag`, `getElementsByClassName` etc. However, where does your problem relate to C#?

Comment: I'm writing this application in C# Form and I just wanted to know if there was any other way to do that. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at webdriver and selenium. These are tools for automated testing.

[webdriver and selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

If `webBrower.Document.GetElementById("Id_Of_Element").InvokeMembers("Click")` works then you can use this:

```
webBrower.Document.GetElementById('<%= YourElement.ClientID %>').InvokeMembers("Click")
```

or you can try this:

```
document.getElementById('<%= YourElement.ClientID %>').click()
```

Returning to the problem with IDs, starting from ASP.NET 4.0  you can use [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property for you element. And if you set it into `Static` then the `ClientID` value will be set to the value of the ID property:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

will be rendered as something like this:

```
 <input id="TextBox1" name="ctl00$MasterPageBody$ctl00$TextBox1" />
```